# How to find and change values of rows before a certain value?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series like this:

```
series = pd.Series([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 2])
```

How can I change all the values `0` before `1` (for example to `NaN`)? So the series should become:

```
[0, 0, NaN, 1, 2, 3, 0, NaN, 1, 2]
```

I was trying to generate:

```
series_shift = series.shift(-1)
```

The problem then is to find and replace the first `-1` values for every block of `-1`, but I can't figure it out either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `series.eq()` and `shift(-1)` together with an `&` to check if current value is 0 and next value is 1 , then use [`series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)

```
series.mask(series.eq(0) & series.shift(-1).eq(1))
```

---

```
0    0.0
1    0.0
2    NaN
3    1.0
4    2.0
5    3.0
6    0.0
7    NaN
8    1.0
9    2.0
dtype: float64
```